# Including openFrameworks in MonoDevelop

Tags: monodevelop, openframeworks

How do I include openFrameworks in a MonoDevelop C/C++ Project?

I set the include path to the `OF_ROOT/libs` and can do `#include <openFrameworks/ofMain.h>` but I get an error that says the `"ofConstants.h"` file does not exist, but it does. It is somewhere in the `OF_ROOT/libs/openFrameworks/` subdirectory.

`ofMain.h` includes the files like ofConstants.h like so `#include "ofConstants.h"`

Help! :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like openFrameworks has a strange setup for their headers, and needs include paths for all the subdirectories: https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/blob/master/apps/devApps/fboTester/emptyExample_linux.cbp#L47